# Closing bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons on modal, on first I need to save changes and close modal, on second I need to close modal and reset changes - same thing when person closes modal by clicking anywhere. The problem is I don't know how to check whether save button was clicked.

Here is html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNumber" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalNumberLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          blablabla
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn-u btn-u-default" type="button">{{ 'backButton'|trans }}</button>
             <button type="submit" class="btn-u saveChanges">{{ 'confirmChangesButton'|trans }}</button>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is JS code:

```
$('.saveChanges').on('click', function () {
    // doing something here 
    // ....


    // and closing modal in the end
    $(this).closest('.modal.fade').modal('hide');;
});

$('.modal.fade').each(function(index, object) {
    $(object).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target);


        // here is part of irrelevant code - what's important is that I use index and I need to know if saveButton was clicked
        mainContainer.resetGroup(index);
    });
});
```

**`e.target` always returns `div class="modal fade"` element, not the button**

What's important - I don't want to call `mainContainer.resetGroup(index);` when save button was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a function to your save-btn you don't need to know which button was clicked. In my example are two functions, similar to your example. The first function is called when the save-btn is clicked. In this function you can fetch the data, which you have to save and save it (e.g. via ajax).

The second method is called every time when the modal is closed. But when the save-btn was pressed, the first function was invoked before, and therefore you don't need to check any more which button was pressed...

You just need to replace the alert(data) function with your 'save procedure'. I hope that I didn't misunderstood your question...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.save-btn').on('click', function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();

      var $btn = $(this);
      var $modal = $btn.closest('.modal');
      var data = $modal.find('form').serializeArray();

      // save data
      alert(data);

      // close modal
      $modal.modal('hide');

  });

  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(evt) {

     alert('modal was hidden -- clear input fields'); 
      $('#myModal').find('input').val('');
  });
});
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/216q3jgk/4/

**EDIT**:
In the case that you would know which button was pressed, I would suggest to add a data-attribute to your modal, when the save-btn is pressed.
To add the data attribute call this in the first function before the modal is closed:

```
    $modal.data('savePressed', true);
```

The data-attribute can be checked in the `hidden.bs.modal` function with the following code:

```
    var $modal = $(evt.target);
    if (!$modal.data('savePressed')) {
        // save button was NOT pressed
        alert('save not pressed');   
    }
```

You can find a full example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/216q3jgk/5/

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, but there a little missunderstanding - in second function I DON'T WANT to call this line - mainContainer.resetGroup(index); - when save button was clicked.

Comment: OK, then I would suggest to add a `data-attribute` to your modal when the save-btn is pressed. You can check the attribute value in the `hidden.bs.modal` function. (see https://jsfiddle.net/216q3jgk/5/)

Comment: add this to Your answer :)